# How to escape characters in JSON response for SQL INSERT FROM OPENJSON via PYTHON

Tags: sql-server, python-3.x, open-json

Getting error when sending API JSON response to SQL Server db due to apostrophe in the values ('). See second JSON response for **operator_country_lar**

Here is a sample API response:

```
json_response= '{
"num_results": 455161,
"results": [
    {
        "activity_date": "1975-12-01",
        "activity_id": "50",
        "activity_name": "ORDERED",
        "operator_country_lar": "France",
        "registered_owner_name": "AIR FRANCE"
    },
    {
        "activity_date": "1974-10-01",
        "activity_id": "50",
        "activity_name": "ORDERED",
        "operator_country_lar": "Korea, Democratic People's Republic of",
        "registered_owner_name": "KOREAN AIR LINES"
    }
],
"results_this_page": 2,
"status": 200}'
```

Serializing the response and executing:

```
query = "DECLARE @json nvarchar(max)= "+json_response+" INSERT INTO "+self.database+"([activity_date],[activity_name],[operator_name]) 
SELECT * FROM OPENJSON(@json, '$.results') WITH (activity_date date, activity_name nchar(25), operator_name nchar(256))"


cursor.execute(query)
cnxn.commit()
```

The first instance works fine, but the second set in the response throws an error. How do I escape the apostrophe or is there a more accurate way to write the SQL OPENJSON statement in PYTHON?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This search and replace worked. It may not be perfect but it's relatively fast in processing json. Hope it helps someone.

```
self.response = json.loads(json.dumps(self.response.json()).replace("'", ""))
```

Please share below if you find a better solution.